# How to get the files with a prefix in Pyspark from s3 bucket?

Tags: csv, file, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have different files in my s3. Now I want to get the files which starts with `cop_` . To achieve that I have tried the below:-

```
source = s3-path
files = [filename for filename in dbutils.fs.ls(source) if filename.startswith('cop_ ')]
print(files)
```

When tried it I am getting an error as below:-

```
AttributeError: 'FileInfo' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

S3 folder has this file names below:-

```
cop_new.csv
public_new.csv
cop_old.csv
public_old.csv
```

Excepted output:-

```
[cop_new.csv,cop_old.csv]
```

Comment: Can you try `filename.name.startswith('cop_ ')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing a `FileInfo` object when calling `.startswith()` and not a string.

The filename is a property of the `FileInfo` object, so `filename.name.startswith('cop_ ')` should work.